# Use Imagemagick to create a bar with text at top of image and a different text bar at the bottom

Tags: imagemagick

Trying to create a solid 1920X1920 transparent canvas, then put a 1920X420 colored bar at the top with centered text and the same at the bottom with different centered text.

What I am doing now, when it gets created creates the 1920X1920 transparent image and puts the bar at the top with the text, but the bar at the bottom is non-existent.

```
convert -size 1920x1920 xc:"transparent" -size 1920x420 -font 
Din-Condensed-Bold -pointsize 84 canvas:#800000 -fill black -
gravity center  caption:"TEXT FOR THE BOTTOM"   -gravity south  
-composite -size 1920x420 -font Din-Condensed-Bold -pointsize 84 
canvas:#800000 -fill black -gravity center  caption:"TEXT FOR THE 
TOP"   -gravity north  -composite newfile.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things...

The main issue is that you set the background colour for a label with `-background` rather than `canvas:`.

Note that `-font`, `-size`, `-pointsize` and `-fill` are **settings**, as such they only need setting once and then they remain set until changed, so you don't need to keep repeating them.

Your command then becomes like this:

```
convert -size 1920x1920 xc:yellow \
    -size 1920x420 -font "AppleChancery"  -pointsize 84 -background "#800000" -fill black \
    -gravity center  caption:"TEXT FOR THE BOTTOM" -gravity south -composite         \
    -gravity center  caption:"TEXT FOR THE TOP"    -gravity north -composite result.png
```

[image]

Very Spanish, don't you think? :-)

---

In case you were actually looking for `-undercolor`:

```
convert -size 1920x1920 xc:yellow \
    -size 1920x420 -font "AppleChancery"  -pointsize 84 -background magenta -undercolor cyan -fill black \
    -gravity center  caption:"TEXT FOR THE BOTTOM" -gravity south -composite         \
    -gravity center  caption:"TEXT FOR THE TOP"    -gravity north -composite result.png
```

[image]

---

You say you want some *"breathing space"* around the edges, so I am adding a further example. I make the red and yellow boxes slightly smaller than the magenta background and position the top one inset 5 pixels from the top and 5 from the left using `-geometry`. Likewise, I set gravity to SouthWest and position the yellow box 2 pixels from the right edge and 25 from the bottom:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:magenta -size 90x20               \
   -gravity northwest xc:red    -geometry +5+5  -composite \
   -gravity southeast xc:yellow -geometry +2+25 -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: This was brilliant.  Thanks @Mark.  I forgot to ask, is it possible to add padding to just the banners?  I was able to use -border to add the padding, but it gets applied to the entire image when I just want it on the top banner and bottom banner.  If  you want, I can create a separate question so I can give you the points. :)

Comment: Try adding `-bordercolor blue  -border x35` just before the output filename. That means you are only setting a height for the border and no width, so it doesn't get applied to the sides.

Comment: That put it around the whole thing.  So, instead of a blue border around the entire 1920x1920 space. I’m trying to

Comment: Put one around the pink banner at the top and one around the pink banner at the bottom per your example above.  Basically I’m trying to add text padding more than a border.  So maybe there’s another way.  I just don’t want the text butting all the way against the edges of the box it is in.

Comment: I have to go offline in a minute. Make a new question, with an example of what you want and one of the other guys will pick it up, or I'll get to it later. Questions are free :-)

Comment: I added an example of a *"breathing space"* at the bottom of my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up on this.  I haven't had a chance yet to make another question, but thanks much for adding that anyway.